# Sql query to return information about customers which has spent the most amount

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database about the shop, and I need to return full information of the first 5 customers, which has spent the most amount, and in returned results also display that total amount. (counting all
his/her payments together from the payments table). Order descending by the total amount.
Can someone help with the query for this?

Customers Table
[image]

Payments Table
[image]

Comment: JOIN, GROUP BY, SUM, ORDER BY, LIMIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this. You might have to play around but it will give you a good start.

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, SUM(p.amount) AS Total
FROM CustomersTable c
INNER JOIN PaymentsTable p
ON c.customerNumber = p.customerNumber
GROUP BY p.customerNumber DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: hm, it shows me that i cant group on total :(

Comment: okay, give me a sec, I'll try to run it in one of my databases

Comment: Maybe try that, I forgot to join the table lol

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'customers.customerNumber' in 'field list'

Comment: I fixed #1054 but still throws error that i cant group on Total

Comment: change group to order by

Comment: now it shows one total sum of all payments in 1 row, but it is not correctly

Comment: group by customer, then you may have to order by Total . Sorry its hard doing it just by head without the database

Comment: Great! Please check it as the correct answer. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT min(c.Customername), SUM(p.amount) AS Total
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN payments p
on c.Customernumber=p.Customernumber

GROUP BY p.Customernumber
order by 2 DESC